# Python code running only in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python

Im a beginner, and im trying to make a code to download stuff, taking links from a txt file, but when I execute the script in the folder it doesn't run, and instead it die instantly (inside vscode it works without any problem).
The problem I think is   `with open` , but I don't know how to solve it...

```
with open("input.txt") as test:
   links = [x.rstrip() for x in test]
```

If I remove this part of the code it works perfectly

Comment: My suspicion is it's looking for the txt file in the script's directory, rather than the current working directory, i.e. where you're executing the script from.

Comment: But how can I tell him to look for the file inside the current working directory?

Comment: if you just want ot work the script for now, provide absolute file path not relative one

Comment: Either full file path as suggested above or open the folder with script in vscode and add the txt file to same folder. When `open` encounters just a file name, it checks in the current working directory only.

Comment: @Al3xw4r you can try `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'input.txt')` to see if that works

Comment: @rv.kvetch Still not working when I execute the .py file, it just work inside vscode (the txt file is inside the same folder)

Comment: @Al3xw4r you can use the `__file__` global variable if you want to get the directory of the Python script itself. Am i correct in assuming the txt file is in the same folder as the script you're trying to run?

Comment: Yes it's in the same folder, i wrote that, but im really confused bc inside vscode it works fine, but when i run the script idk why it closes                                                           
```local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, 'input.txt')
with open("input.txt") as fl:
   file_contents = [x.rstrip() for x in fl]

print(file_contents)```